# Why does a generic setter break type covariance, even when it is constrained?

Tags: c#

I have the following interface:

```
public interface ICommand<TMessage> 
    where TMessage : MessageBase 
{
    TMessage Message { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to be able to cast implementations to IMessage but for this to be possible, the type parameter needs to be covariant, like so:

```
public interface ICommand<out TMessage> 
    where TMessage : MessageBase 
{
    TMessage Message { get; set; }
}
```

But then, the compiler complains: The type parameter 'TMessage' must be invariantly valid on ICommand.Message'. 'TMessage' is covariant.
If I remove the setter, everything works just fine.

However, I don't understand why this setter poses a problem theoretically because I have specified that the Message property can only keep reference to instances of more derived types of MessageBase...

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, after giving it a little more thought, it is actually quite easy to see.

Suppose I instantiate a `DerivedCommand<T>` (that implements `ICommand<T>`)

```
var derivedCommand = new DerivedCommand<DerivedMessage>();
```

and then cast it to `ICommand<MessageBase>`

```
var command = (ICommand<MessageBase>) derivedCommand;
```

That would imply that I can now assign any instance of type `MessageBase` to the Message property. But, since the property is actually of type `DerivedMessage` which is more derived than `MessageBase`, it does not work in all cases (where `AnotherMessage` does derive from `MessageBase` but not from `DerivedMessage`). Therefore, setters cannot be covariant even when the type is constrained.

Comment: Don't word your answer as if you didn't already know it before you posted the question. You posted them almost exactly the same time, you don't need to pretend like you "gave it a little more thought"

Comment: ...though I am surprised with such quick upvotes... multiple accounts, or just friends?

Comment: Sorry, but SO just gives the option to ask and answer your question at the same time. Since I figured out why just after finishing my question, I immediately added the response. Formulating that question took more than 5 minutes.

And no multiple accounts. Equally surprised by quick upvotes.

Comment: @musefan, it's [perfectly fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/299295) to post answer and question. I'd ignore wording if problem shown and answered well.

Comment: @Sinatr: Yeah I know, i'm just speaking some thoughts